# Creating a legend, key or color ramp for the color gradient in R's image()

Tags: r, plot

In an R session, given:

```
foo <- matrix(1:25, 5, 5)
image(foo)
```

What is the best way for me to add a legend or key for the color gradient used on this `image()` plot of `foo`?

This is for a large dataset of global precipitation values so hacking something together with `legend()` doesn't seem to be a viable option. `filled.contour()` has a number of side effects that I'm not happy with. I'm using `image()` because it is the simplest plotting method to layer or add onto.

For the moment, my biggest issue with `filled.contour()` is that I'm trying to add contours from a different dataset via `contour()` to the plot. With `filled.contour()`, the contours would need to be adjusted to account for the default gradient key on the side of the plot, though I suppose this would also be the case if I added a key to the `image()` plot.

Thank you kindly for your time.

**For future reference:**

When using `filled.contour()`, you can call `contour()` and/or `map()` in addition to any other function you like by assigning it to `filled.contour()`'s `plot.axes` argument. It might be helpful to remember that you can stack multiple lines of code with braces.

Comment: Can you edit your question to specify what, precisely, the undesirable side effects of `filled.contour` are? It may be easier to subtract from `filled.contour` than add to `image`.

Comment: For the moment, my biggest issue is that I'm trying to add contours from a different dataset via `contours()` to the plot. With `filled.contour()`, the contours would need to be adjusted to account for the default gradient key on the side of the plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some code adapted from the zernike package.  You can use it all, or just pull out the piece which creates a gradient key.
  # written 13 April 2011 by CGWitthoft.  Watch for updates from the
 # owner of the  zernike package.

```
 pupilplot <- function (wf, cp = NULL, col = topo.colors(256), addContours = FALSE, 
cscale = TRUE, ...) 
 {
     if (cscale) {
         mar.orig <- (par.orig <- par(c("mar", "las", "mfrow")))$mar
        on.exit(par(par.orig))
        w <- (3 + mar.orig[2]) * par("csi") * 2.54
        layout(matrix(c(2, 1), ncol = 2), widths = c(1, lcm(w)))
        par(las = 1)
        mar <- mar.orig
        mar[4] <- mar[2]
        mar[2] <- 1
        par(mar = mar) 
    thelist <- list(...)  
    findz <- which(names(thelist) == 'zlim')  
    if (length(findz) > 0 ) {   
        zlim <- thelist$zlim  
        }else{  
                zlim <- range(wf, finite = TRUE) #the original line  
        } 
 # end of my hack  
        levels <- seq(zlim[1], zlim[2], length = length(col))
        plot.new()
        plot.window(xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = range(levels), xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")
        rect(0, levels[-length(levels)], 1, levels[-1], col = col,  density = NA)
        axis(4)
         box()
        mar <- mar.orig
        mar[4] <- 0
        par(mar = mar)
    }
    if (is.null(cp)) {
        axis1 <- 1:nrow(wf)
        axis2 <- 1:ncol(wf)
    }
    else {
         axis1 <- ((1:nrow(wf)) - cp$xc)/cp$rx
        axis2 <- ((1:ncol(wf)) - cp$yc)/cp$ry
    }
    image(axis1, axis2, wf, col = col, asp = 1, xlab = "X", ylab = "Y",  ...)
     if (addContours) 
        contour(axis1, axis2, wf, add = TRUE)
}
```